# Ruby on rails Interpolation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, validation

Am pretty new to ROR. Need help in Rails form validation.
Am using rails 2.3.5
I have a basic validates_presence_of for the fields in the form.
Now when i don't enter field details, i do get an error, but the error is displayed as:

```
{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved  
There were problems with the following fields:  
{{attribute}} {{message}}  
{{attribute}} {{message}}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your model code, specifically the validation methods

Comment: The title of this question is not very meaningful, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error output is related to the internationalisation and translation of error strings in your system.

There may be a mismatch between your version of Rails and the i18n gem that is breaking string interpolations in your locale file e.g. 'en.yml'.

The first thing I would do to try and fix this problem is to update to the latest version of the 2.3.x series of Rails (which is 2.3.9), and then check that your **i18n gem** is also at the latest version (**0.5.0**); because those versions of Rails and i18n have been tested together.

**Background information**

The interpolation syntax "{{foo}}" was deprecated since 0.4.0 version of the i18n gem, and [was removed in version 0.5.0](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/commit/2d43846d2b2a2e596f30fa58ea1c9ddb2243bb64).

The Rails codebase [mirrored this change in interpolation syntax in version 2.3.9](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5ed6a8447b1c9191feb431e1387f28abde7eba44#diff-3).

Comment: Thanks.. upgrading to rails 2.3.9 worked.. :) Was already on 0.5.0v of i18n gem.

Comment: Good to hear! Happy coding :-)

Comment: Alternatively, looks like downgrading to 0.4.0 i18n works as well (couldn't upgrade my rails, but could downgrade the other)